# Simpler way to connect to a DB with NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Connecting to any DB with Java is very simple - I just need the appropriate JAR in the classpath. Alternatively, steps involved in installing any of the (example) Oracle drivers for NodeJS are very complicated (you need the windows sdk, visual studio, python 2.7, a whole bunch of environment variables). This leads me to think I'm missing something. Is there a simpler way to connect?

Comment: It depends on the database and its driver. Some databases are easy, just install a module and you're done. Apparently, for Oracle, all kinds of external libraries are required to be able to connect to it, which complicates the installation procedure. It would figure that Oracle's Java support would be much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Connecting a SQL Database:**
There are node modules which will help you connect to DB. Lets consider mysql as of now:

```
npm install mysql
```

Consider the [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) module. Please have a look at the documentation. From the Docs itself:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

**2.Connecting a NoSQL Database:**
Node.js really works well with NoSQL databases. If you are considering MongoDB,

```
npm install mongodb
```

Then try:

```
// Retrieve
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
  if(err) { return console.dir(err); }

  db.collection('test', function(err, collection) {});

  db.collection('test', {w:1}, function(err, collection) {});

  db.createCollection('test', function(err, collection) {});

  db.createCollection('test', {w:1}, function(err, collection) {});

});
```